# Return an expression that subtracts b from a

Tags: python

I am making a calculator as a school assignment. I have problems with one function:

```
def subtraction(a, b):
return a, "-", b, "=", a - b
```

This function is supposed to return "a - b = c", example: "3 - 2 = 1"
When I push the file to Git I get an email that consists of following errors regarding this particular function:

test_subtraction_3_2: FAILED (2.795 ms)

test_subtraction_floats: FAILED (2.538 ms)

test_subtraction_m_3_m_5: FAILED (2.445 ms)

test_subtraction_random: FAILED (2.598 ms)

I tested this code with print function and executed that file in command prompt and it worked exactly as it should. 
Any kind of help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: That returns a tuple `(a, "-", b, "=", a - b)`.

Answer (score 1):

Try using format like this:

```
def subtraction(a, b):
    return "{} - {} = {}".format(a, b, a-b)
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
def subtraction(a, b):
  return "%s-%s=%s" %(a,b, a - b)
```

Answer (score 0):

`return a, "-", b, "=", a - b` returns a tuple `(a, "-", b, "=", a - b`)

You need to return a `string` concatenation:

`return str(a) + " - " + str(b) + " = " + str(a - b)`

Comment: Ok, thanks - this is more clear now: I edited my answer to reflect the desired a=output.

Answer (score -1):

You need to import math library for additional functions 
Try - and plus have to be used explicitly with out bracket
print(str(a)+str(b))